# Compass issue on Dell tablet

Tags: hardware-failure, windows-tabletpc

The azimuth shown on my Dell tablet Control Center software is reversed when it comes to the East and West, while North and South are correctly aligned. When turning the tablet, the compass turns twice the angle in the same direction instead of staying aligned to the true North, like a good old manual compass would do...

This makes it quite hard to estimate the true bearing (except for N, S and maybe exact E & W) !

I tried to install "Compass One" (free app), but in this case true North is shown as East (90°), true East as South, etc...

I had a look inside the tablet to see if the GPS module could be inverted, but I'm not sure the compass is in this module and it appears to be solded anyway.

The BIOS does not mention the compass or even GPS, or maybe I missed something.

Any idea to solve the issue, maybe a tool or app that could be tweaked ("Compass One" with -90° would be correct apparently), **to give a correct reading ?**

*Dell 7220 rugged 2nd hand so no warranty nor support, Windows 10 Pro. Magnetic declinaison is less than 1° looking at the most recent data for my area.*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is only ONE problem described here, COMPASS ISSUE. I'm just adding as much information as I can...

Comment: i beliv without a support case for dell you will not continue

Comment: I know that phone compass electronics occasionally needs calibration by repeatedly rotating the device in all its axis while in use. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-can-i-calibrate-the-compass-on-my-phone might apply, and I've seen some other "figure 8" patterns as well. Basically rotating and spinning your device entirely around every axis.

Comment: @Mokubai Good thinking, but after a few tries neither the 3 axis rotations method nor the "8" spin worked out (your link helped me calibrate my eWatch, though, both methods together succeeded, while I never could get the compass to work with the S/8 movement indicated on the screen).